# Dynamically adding and re positioning the textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have simple windows form for obtaining the user details. If the user wish to add alternate mobile number by clicking "+" Button , a text box should appear below it and other text boxes should re position themselves according to newly added text box.
I am able to add the text box dynamically at run time but not able to re position the other form component with respect to dynamically added text box. Below is my code and form snapshot. Thanks in advance.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
    txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic" + c++;
    txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 74 + (20 * c));
    txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
    txtRun.Location.X = 90;
    txtRun.Location.Y = 74;
    this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
}
```

[image: User details windows form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
int c = 0; // for uinque txtDynamic text creation 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      TextBox txtDynamic = this.Controls.Find("txtDynamic" + c, true)[0] as TextBox; // find lastly added txtDynamic 

      TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
      txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic" + ++c;
      txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
      txtRun.Location = new Point(txtDynamic.Location.X, txtDynamic.Location.Y + 35); // X axis will be same y will increase with count 35


      foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
      {
           if (item.Location.Y >= txtRun.Location.Y){ // if there is an item that has greater Y location
               item.Location = new Point(item.Location.X, txtRun.Location.Y + 35); // It should increase its value as 35 too.
           }
           this.Controls.Add(txtRun);

      }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Okay, I have created controls with drag and drop, I don't know if you created them programatically. **+** Button will add new textboxes after the Mobil TextBox. So Mobile TextBox that I dragged and droped will be the top point. So I gave it's name as "**txtDynamic0**",

[image]

Put breakpoint on `button1_click`, your `c` variable has a value different then 0 for the starting point I guess.

**Result;**
[image]

Hope helps,

Comment: I am getting exception Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: I gave Mobile textbox's Id as txtDynamic0 for initial. Thats why I use ++c instead of c++. Change Id of Mobile Textbox. Thats why you got bounds of array exception.

Comment: Id? do u mean Name of textbox

Comment: @SameerBetageri sorry, you are right name of textbox.

Comment: @berkey still same error can u please elaborate what to be done

Comment: @SameerBetageri See edit please. Check your c variable at button_click. It should start from 0 in my case. You need to get always last added txtDynamic control. For the initiation you have got only "txtDynamic0" that I gave manual. If your `c` variable is 1; for the initiation there is no `txtDynamic1` and `this.controls.find()` will throw index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding all your controls (name, email, mobile, city etc) to a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) and add this to your window:

```
var panel = new FlowLayoutPanel() { FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown }
panel.Controls.Add(namePanel);
panel.Controls.Add(emailPanel);
// etc
```

When the user clicks the `+` button, insert the new control(s) at the required position:

```
panel.Controls.Insert(3, newControlPanel); // add new control at index #3
```

If you haven't already done so, you will probably need to wrap each `Label`-`TextBox` pair in its own `Panel` so that the flow layout works as expected. This can be done programmatically:

```
private void InitializeForm()
{
    var layoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    // todo: initialize flow layout panel here...

    layoutPanel.Controls.Add(CreatePanel("Name"));
    layoutPanel.Controls.Add(CreatePanel("Email"));
    // etc

    this.Controls.Add(layoutPanel);
}

private Panel CreatePanel(string labelText)
{
    var label = new Label(labelText);
    // todo: initialize label here...

    var textBox = new TextBox();
    // todo: initialize textbox here...

    var panel = new Panel();
    panel.Controls.Add(label);
    panel.Controls.Add(textBox);
    // todo: initialize panel here...

    return panel;
}
```

As each panel is added in exactly the same way, this method also helps your form look more consistent. For example, margins and padding can all be changed in one location.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Form` object has it's `Controls` where are listed & stored all the objects. You are accesing it also and adding Your `TextBox` in this code:

```
this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
```

You can decide how handle the case as there are more solutions. You can either go through all the Controls, find that are below the `MobileTextBox` and move them few pixels down.

Or You can group the controls below the `MobileTextBox` into some `GroupBox` (or other grouping control) and then just move the `GroupBox`.

And/or is the solution mentioned by @gt - `FlowLayoutPanel` which will handle the layout in similar way as the `WPF framework` does.

Some code examples:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
    txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic" + c++;
    txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 74 + (20 * c));
    this.Controls.Add(txtRun);

    //removed some code for brevity


    //1st solution
    foreach(Control item in this.Controls)
    {
        //there can be some other condition
        //based on e.g. name of TB
        //or if the type is GroupBox with some name

        if(item.Location.Y >= txtRun.Location.Y)
           item.Location.Y = item.Location.Y + 25; 

    }

}
```